# Searching for values from one dataframe in another and returning information in the corresponding row/different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 Dataframes:

```
df_Billed: pd.Dataframe({'Bill_Number':[220119, 220120, 220219, 220219, 220419, 220519, 220619, 221219],'Date': [1/31/2019, 2/20/2020, 2/28/2019, 6/30/2019,6/30/2019,6/30/2019,6/30/2019,12/31/2019], 'Amount': [3312.5, 832.0,10000.0, -3312.5,8725.0,1862.5,3637.5,1587.5]})

df_Received: pd.Dataframe({'Bill_Number':[220119, 220219, 220419, 220519, 220619],'Date':[4/16/2019,5/21/2019,8/2/2019,8/2/2019,8/2/2019],'Amount':[3312.5,6687.5,8725,1862.5,3637.5]})
```

I am trying to search for for each "Bill_Number" in df_Billed to see if it is present if df_Received. Ideally, if it is present, I would like to take the difference between the dates between df_Billed and df_Received for that particular bill number (to see how many days it took to get paid). If the billing number is not present in df_Received, I would like to simply return the all rows for that billing number in df_Billed.

```
EX: Since df_Billed Bill_Number 220119 is in df_Received, it would return 75 (which is the number of days it took for the bill to be paid 4/16/2019 - 1/31/2019). 

EX: Since df_Billed Bill_Number 221219 is not in df_Received, it would return 12/31/2019 (which is the date it was billed).
```

Comment: Your Bill_Number should be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use [merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCuJR.png) on Bill_Number initially

```
df_Billed=df_Billed.merge(df_Received,on='Bill_Number',how='left')
```

Then use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for computing diffrence between dates

```
df_Billed['result']=df_Billed.apply(lambda x:x.Date_x if pd.isnull(x.Date_y) 
                    else abs(pd.to_datetime(x.Date_x)-pd.to_datetime(x.Date_y)).days, 
                    axis=1)
```

And finally, I think you want to create a new column for final result..so I'm renaming the merged columns Date_x and Amount_y back to Date and Amount below:

```
df_Billed.drop(['Date_y','Amount_y'],axis=1,inplace=True)
df_Billed.rename(columns={"Date_x": "Date","Amount_x":"Amount"},inplace=True)
```

**Final Dataframe:**

[image]

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you so much.